# How can I center a Tabbedpage inside of a ContentPage?

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

The problem I'm having is wanting to be able to add a tabbed page inside a Contepage, but I need to do it as seen in the following image, as you can see this is an image above the tab view and I'd like to be able to display different content on that tab view, what would you recommend to be able to resolve this?

[imagenhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF5rA.png)

What I was trying was with tabbedpage but it doesn't give me the same result since I need to put the `<Image>` before and it tells me that I can't use Contepage tags, any alternative?

`

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <views:HomePage Title="Home" />
    <views:AboutPage Title="About" />
    <views:ContactPage Title="Contact" />
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

`

Comment: You can’t put a TabbedPage inside a ContentPage.  Use a TabView instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TabView` control allows the user to display a set of tabs and their content. The TabView is fully customizable, other than the native tab bars. However, this hasn't been implemented in **CommunityToolkit.Maui**.

For more details, you can refer to https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/121.

Last but not least, there are many awesome packages to achieve the `TabView` in **Maui**, you can refer to this as an alternative solution:

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs

https://github.com/syncfusion/maui-demos/tree/master/MAUI/TabView/SampleBrowser.Maui.TabView